# How to make an 'await' for multiple variables on return async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an `async` function:

```
public async Task<List<Data>> GetDataAsync()
{
    //get data
    return new List<Data>; //but then filled with real data
}
```

And I am calling it like so:

```
listView.ItemsSource = await sc.GetSensorsAsync();
```

So that the listView will be popuplated when the function is done getting the data.

Now I would like to save the same `List<Data>` to a variable, but without calling the `sc.GetSensorDataAsync()` again.

I tried this:

```
List<Data> data = await sc.GetSensorsAsync();
listView.ItemsSource = data;
```

But because the function is async, it will execute the `listView.ItemsSource = data;` when the `data` variable is still `null`.

How do I solve this so that both `listView.ItemsSource` and `data` will contain the returned value?

Comment: `But because the function is async, it will execute the listView.ItemsSource = data; when the data variable is still null` how is that possible when you put await before assigning data? maybe method is returning null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But because the function is async, it will execute the
>   listView.ItemsSource = data; when the data variable is still null.

No, that isn't how async-await works. The async method will only execute the continuation (the line after the `await`) once the asynchronous method has completed. That means, it is guaranteed that `GetSensorsAsync` will complete before your next line which assigns the list to the `ListView.ItemSource`.

If you're receiving a `null` value then it is only because your method is returning `null`.